# C# Build a List of Tasks from different injected services and execute them one by one

Tags: c#, .net-core, task

So I want to build a `List<Task<bool>>` from different injected services in .NET Core 3.1. This is my code:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<bool>>()
{
    subscriptionService.ValidatePurchases(),
    serviceTwo.Task(),
    serviceThree.TaskTwo()
};

tasks.ForEach(task =>
{
    var fieldInfo = typeof(Task).GetField("m_action", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    Delegate action = fieldInfo.GetValue(task) as Delegate;
    string methodName = action?.Method.Name ?? "null";

    try
    {
        task.Start();
        task.Wait();

        if (!task.Result)
        {
            Log.Warning($"Scheduled task: ({methodName}) returned false in TaskRunner.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex, $"Scheduled task: ({methodName}) threw an unhandled exception in TaskRunner.");
    }
});
```

Problem is that the tasks are instantly executed. How can I maintain a list that doesn't execute until I would call the `Start` method on the task?

Comment: That means `subscriptionService.ValidatePurchases()` etc already return started tasks, so you cannot do anything in the provided code to change that. That said returning non-started task is VERY rare and is usually a bad practice, so unless you create the task yourself chances are it will be already started anyway.

Comment: Keep a list of `Func<Task<bool>>` instead?

Comment: @trashr0x seems to work as long as the Task actually does something. I made some fake tasks that returned false. But that doesn't work. If there is actually some logic like getting database data the task did not start yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to trashr0x I found a solution.

```
var tasks = new List<Func<Task<bool>>>()
{
    () => subscriptionService.ValidatePurchases(),
    () => serviceTwo.Task()
};

tasks.ForEach(async taskMethod =>
{
    try
    {
        var task = taskMethod();

        var result = await task;
        
        if (result) { // do something }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log something
    }
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve within `tasks.ForEach`, i.e. what problem are you trying to  solve?

Comment: @trashr0x this list will be long and each individual task will throw exceptions, because that is the way we catch errors in our services. Instead of adding a `try catch` to each task and logging it's exception I wanted to make short, scalable solution. This code is in a Hosted Service which will run every 20 seconds. So if a exception was thrown it would exit out the loop. If I would've put all tasks in a single `try catch` then not all tasks would get executed on an exception.

Comment: Mind you that since all of your methods return `Task`s you should ideally `await` them - you are blocking each time using `task.Wait()` - you would be better off going `async` all the way, i.e. `await task;`, etc.

Comment: @trashr0x I've edited my answer. Had already found this in project but forgot to update my answer here. Thanks